# NVM giving error while doing nvm ls

Tags: node.js, nvm

I was trying to install and switch between node version, so i first install nvm using below

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~ user.name$ sudo npm install nvm -g
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nvm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nvm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
/usr/local/bin/nvm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm
nvm@0.0.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm
└── mkdirp@0.3.5
```

After this i was trying to do "nvm ls" to list node version but it gave me an error(below). **Please advice what's wrong with it**

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~ user.name$ nvm ls

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm-ls'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: Curious if you were able to resolve this? I also run into this issue, even after exporting my PATH as an answer below recommends.

Answer (score 52):

I recently ran into this problem after I installed nvm as an npm package (from https://npmjs.org/package/nvm).

To resolve the issue, install nvm directly using the instructions at https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

Once installed and

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

ran (this is important, as it makes nvm available in your current terminal session), then you'll be able to run

```
nvm ls
```

and other nvm commands successfully from your project directory.

Hope this helps & cheers to learning node!

Answer (score 5):

To use the **nvm** command you need to source it as described above. But you don't want to do this after every login.

Just add these lines to your *~/.bashrc*, *~/.profile*, or *~/.zshrc* file to have it automatically sourced upon login:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

See also https://github.com/creationix/nvm#manual-install

Comment: From https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script
Note: On OSX, if you get nvm: command not found after running the install script, your system may not have a [.bash_profile file] where the command is set up. **Simple create one with touch ~/.bash_profile and run the install script again.**

Answer (score 2):

just to add, I use mac as well but non default shell (zsh)
installing nvm will modify .bash_profile (and add line of "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh")

so I was getting same error, you need to make sure you need to add "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" to your shell profile file (for me it was .zshrc)

Answer (score 1):

@jewel is correct: As of January 2016 (and maybe earlier), the NPM-installed version of nvm no longer seems to exist (at least, its [github repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm) gives a 404). If this old, unmaintained package is installed, you may see errors like `"local" not implemented yet` or `Error: Cannot find module './nvm-help'` when typing nvm commands.

The correct version of **nvm** now comes from https://github.com/creationix/nvm

If you have installed the earlier (now unmaintained) version, you can get back on the air by doing these steps:

1. `npm uninstall -g nvm`
2. Using the Install Script on the github page above

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your path to include ./node_modules/.bin?  E.g.:

```
export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

my solving
nano ~/.zshrc
add export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
then restart terminal

Comment: **Firstly** You need to include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable **Secondly** While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how & why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer